# Javascript innerHTML и textContent

Tags: javascript

```
<div>></div>
```

Нужно вывести то, что находиться между блоком div

Когда я его алертом вывожу по свойству `innerHTML`, выводится `&gt;`

а когда вывожу через `textContent`, то все нормально выводиться символ `>`

Как избавиться от этого? Я бы использовал `textContent` но он же не кросбраузерный ?

Comment: Нужно что бы символы выводились такие как есть

Answer (score 3):

```
var text = textContent || innerText;
```

Comment: O_O

это работает? 

var text = textContent || innerText; Разве у этого выражения не логический результат будет?

Т.е. по томуже принципу можно кросбраузерно создавать объект XMLHttpRequest?


var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest() || new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP") || ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");



Или что я не правильно понял?

Comment: @VasyaVasya, да, в JavaScript это работает. Запись аналогична

   var text = textContent ? textContent : innerText;

Comment: @VasyaVasya, в javascript логические операторы возвращают не булево значение, а значение переменной или выражения

Comment: Спасибо, можно пожалуйста ссылку где про это почитать?

Просто не совсем принцип ее работы понял.

function A(){return "123";}
function B(){return "321";}

alert(A() && B()); 

По идее алерт должен вывести 123321, а выводит 321. В чем дело?

Comment: @VasyaVasya, смотрите, что возвращают операторы по таблице в статье:[Логические операторы](http://javascript.ru/boolean-operators). Правда в данном примере стоит учесть, что в браузерах без поддержки textContent вы все равно получите мнемонику &gt.

Это связано с тем, что не обязательно проверять все значения, что бы вычислить результат выражения. При || возвращается первое верное выражение(дальше нет смысла сравнивать) или последнее, а при && первое неверное(дальше нет смысла сравнивать) или последнее, если все верны.

Comment: @VasyaVasya, 

> По идее алерт должен вывести 123321, а выводит 321. В чем дело?

A() && B()  - сдесь и A() и B() возвращают true, то есть цифры. А если все выражения true, то возвращается последнее